# Writing code for reservations(API)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have done most of the app I'm working on and now I think I'm stuck in one change. I have the ideas of doing it but the problem I really couldn't implementing it. I hope I can find some help here.

I have this complicated code. It takes two dates and check car_reservation pivot tables for overlapping.

```
 $table->integer('car_id')->unsigned();
 $table->foreign('car_id')->references('id')->on('cars');

 $table->integer('reservation_id')->unsigned();
 $table->foreign('reservation_id')->references('id') >on('reservations');
```

The relationship is in Reservation model :

```
 public function cars()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Access\Car','car_reservation');
}
```

Here is the code that I'm trying to debug and make it work:

```
public function get(Request $request)
{

   $appointments = Reservation::with('cars')->get();

   foreach ($appointments as $appointment) {

     $from = Carbon::parse($request->from);
     $to = Carbon::parse($request->to);
     $eventStart = Carbon::instance(new DateTime($appointment['dt_start']));
     $eventEnd = Carbon::instance(new DateTime($appointment['dt_end']))->subSecond(1);

     // A spot is taken if either the from or to date is between eventStart and eventEnd
     // or if the evenStart and eventEnd are between the from and to date.

      if ($from->between($eventStart, $eventEnd) || 
       $to->between($eventStart, $eventEnd) ||
      ($eventStart->between($from, $to) &&
       $eventEnd->between($from, $to))) {
            return response()->json('false');// test response 
      }
            return response()->json('no appointments overlapping');
      }
}
```

But What I need help with is writing these steps, and I think it would work perfectly.

(1) A method to get the appoitmenets from `car_reservation` within an optional date range. Ex: `getAppointments($from=null,$to=null`

(2) method to loop all the cars and arrange them in array. Ex: `getCars`

(3) A method to check availability. Ex: `isSlotAvailable($from,$to,$appoitments);`

(4) A method that does the work:

```
function getAvailability(Request $request)
{
    $slots = [];

    $from = $request->input('from');

    $to = $request->input('to');

    foreach ($this->getcars() as $cars) {

        $appointments = $this->getAppointments($cars, $from, $to);

        $slot[$cars] = $this->isSlotAvailable($from, $to, $appointments);
    }

    return $slots;
}
```

Then at the end I hope to get something like `['Car' => true, 'Car' => false]`

You help will be really appreciated. I've been coming up with many codes but they all look like my original one.

**UPDATE**

```
public static function findAppointmentsBetweenDates($start, $end)
{
    $appointments = Reservation::wherenotBetween('from_date',array($start,$end))->get();

    return $appointments;
}
```

then in my controller

```
public function get(Request $request)
{
    $results = array();

    $car = Car::doesntHave('reservations')->get();


    if (!$car->isEmpty()) {
        $results[] = $car;

        return Response::json(['array'],$results);
    }


$from = Carbon::parse($request->from)->addHour(2);
    $to = Carbon::parse($request->to);

    $appointmentsBetweenDates = Reservation::findAppointmentsBetweenDates($from, $to);

    foreach ($appointmentsBetweenDates as $appointment)
    {
        $results = ($appointment->cars);


    }
    return Response::json(['array',$results]);
    }
```

Comment: "A spot is taken if either the from or to date is between eventStart and eventEnd or if the evenStart and eventEnd are between the from and to date." Could another way of expressing this idea be: "Event A can be said to overlap Event B if Event A *starts* before Event B *ends* and *ends* after Event B *starts*."?

Comment: this is one of the possibilities, so yes it could be said to overlap.

Comment: No. This is ALL of the possibilities

Comment: @Strawberry my question this time is about refactoring my method. I appreciate your explanation for the possibilities of overlapping:)

Comment: What datatype are you using to store your `dt_start` and `dt_end` in your database? Also, am I correct in assuming that your `get()` method is in your controller and your `getAvailability()` method is in your `Reservation` model?

Comment: it's Datetime. and both `get` and `getAvailability()` in my controller

Comment: `getAvailability()` is the future method I want to come up with but couldn't because I'm lost refactoring the (1)(2)(3)(4) steps

Comment: You really should have working code before you refactor. It seems to me you are debugging.

Comment: Can you write the SQL statements needed?

Comment: look at nkconnor's answer

Answer (score 2):

We can leverage the power of the database to filter available cars in the time slot. Using query builder we can look for every car that *does not* have a reservation during the specified window.

In `Car`

```
/**
 * @param $from Carbon
 * @param $to Carbon
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
 */
public static function whereAvailableBetween($from, $to) {
    $rows = DB::table('car')
        ->leftJoin('car_reservation', 'car_reservation.car_id', '=', 'car.id')
        ->leftJoin('reservation', function($join) use ($from, $to) {
            return $join->on('reservation.id', '=', 'car_reservation.reservation.id')
                ->where('reservation.date_start', '>=', $from->toDateTimeString())
                ->where('reservation.date_end', '<=', $to->toDateTimeString());
        })
        ->whereNull('reservation.id')
        ->get();

    return $rows->map(function($r, $k) {
        return new static($r);
    });
}
```

Now, we can use `\Car::whereAvailableBetween($date_start, $date_end)`. To return it as JSON from your controller, you could:

```
public function get(Request $request)
{
    return Car::whereAvailableBetween(Carbon::parse($request->from), Carbon::parse($request->to));
}
```

**EDIT**

I missed that the desired end format is

> ['Car' => true, 'Car' => false]

So you could modify the above method and return a standard collection with these details by removing the `whereNull` clause:

```
/**
 * @param $from Carbon
 * @param $to Carbon
 * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
 */
public static function whereAvailableBetween($from, $to) {
    $rows = DB::table('car')
        ->leftJoin('car_reservation', 'car_reservation.car_id', '=', 'car.id')
        ->leftJoin('reservation', function($join) use ($from, $to) {
            return $join->on('reservation.id', '=', 'car_reservation.reservation.id')
                ->where('reservation.date_start', '>=', $from->toDateTimeString())
                ->where('reservation.date_end', '<=', $to->toDateTimeString());
        })
        ->select('car.*', 'reservation.id AS reservation_id')
        //->whereNull('reservation.id') if it is null then no reservation, else there is a reservation
        ->get();

    return $rows->map(function($row, $k) {
        $asArray = (array)$row;
        $reservation_id = array_pop($asArray);
        $available = (is_null($reservation_id)) ? true: false;

        return [
            'car' => new static($asArray),
            'available' => $available
        ];
    });
}
```

Keep in mind that you can also add an attribute to a model. So we could do  `$car->available = true`

Comment: I get this error `: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'car_reservation.reservations.id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select * from cars`. I think there's an issue with column's name in your code.btw, what do you think of my answer?I just updated it for you to see it, you will still get the 100 points if your code works

Comment: can you proofread the Query builder schema? it's hard for me to guess at the right table/column names. This one might be a simple typo and needs to be `car_reservation.reservation_id`. Re: update, it is looking good but remember that `$appointment->cars` can result in a n+1 type situation. Checkout eager loading in the docs or just piece my query builder solution into there. Also, remember to group by cars so there are no duplicates

Comment: you are right I fixed all the table/column names but now I'm trying to understand why it throws this error `"Illegal offset type in isset or empty",`

Comment: you might benefit from a debugger. also, you could post a new detailed question on SO with the particulars